# Equal size of flex item while breaking the last item to next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wanted my flex items to have an equal size without setting its width.
I know it can be done by setting the flex item to `flex: 1;`.
However, I also wanted to break the last item into the next line but keep its width equal to the other item, now I'm stuck.

How can I do that?

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
li{
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li class="keep-next-line">7</li> <!--Kepp this next line, but size should be equal to other item-->
</ul>
```

Comment: you need 6 element per row, so you divide by 6 and no need flex:1

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Fair enough, that's the confusing part for me, divided by 7 because of the border. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `flex-grow:0` and should be `calc(100% / 6)` instead of `calc(100% / 7)`. Also I added `box-sizing:border-box;` for borders to be included in width.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 6);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.keep-next-line {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li class="keep-next-line">7</li>
  <!--Kepp this next line, but size should be equal to other item-->
</ul>
```

Comment: simply removing flex:1 is enough, the main change is the 6 divider you made instead of 7

Comment: @TemaniAfif `box-sizing: border-box` is also required.

Comment: I should have rest for a while to reset my brain, I keep dividing 7 because of the border and I didn't realize using `flex: 1;` is already redundant.